# Can we have access js variable in custom tag jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I access a JavaScript variable value in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536213/how-can-i-access-a-javascript-variable-value-in-jsp)

Can we have access java script variable in custom tag jsp?

Answer (score 1):

JSP tags are evaluated on server, before the page is served to client and javascript is run. So, you cannot access variables from javascript in your JSP tags without making additional requests, for example via AJAX.